# Could not load content for CreatedProjects/angular-route.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

// HTML Simple LogIn page //

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login_style.css" />
    <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <title>Login Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="loginCtrl" ng-submit="submit()">
      <form action="/" id="login">
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="username"
            ng-model="username"
            placeholder="Username"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            ng-model="password"
            placeholder="Password"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="button" id="submit" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
          <a href="forgot_password" id="forgot_password">Lost your Password?</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <hr color="gray" width="350px" />
    <a href="forgot_password" id="Create_Acc">New to site? Create Account</a>
```

// Controller or script for validation // - I have checked and its working somehow i get error in browser

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "Login.html",
    })
    .when("/dashboard", {
      templateUrl: "dashboard.html",
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/",
    });
});

app.controller("loginCtrl", function ($scope, $location) {
  $scope.submit = function () {
    var uname = $scope.username;
    var password = $scope.password;
    if ($scope.username == "admin" && $scope.password == "admin") {
      $location.path("/dashboard");
    } else {
      alert("Wrong credentials");
    }
  };
});

</script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Error : DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:5500/e2e/CreatedProjects/angular-route.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: Note I have created a Login Page and a Controller Page differently

Answer (score 0):

try reducing your angular version to 1.6 or something
else try downloading this [file](https://code.angularjs.org/1.8.2/angular-route.min.js.map) and placing it into your CreatedProjects folder.